# 2 buttons, same action, how do I tell which button triggered the action in Ember

Tags: events, button, view, ember.js

I have a simple button that has an action.

```
<button {{action "slide" target="view"}} class="slide up">Slide up</button>
```

Make that two,

```
<button {{action "slide" target="view"}} class="slide left">Slide down</button>
```

Both of these have the same action that is handled by the containing view, something like this:

```
App.ViewName = Ember.View.extend({
   actions:{
      slide: function(){
            console.log("which button triggered the slide action?");
       }
   }

});
```

In the above piece of code, my console log states my quandary. I am not sure how I can identify which button {the Slide Up OR the Slide Down} triggered the slide action.

I mean, this is basic straightforward stuff in jQuery where you can simply use the 'event' to determine the calling button. But in Ember, all these concepts seem to desert me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

honestly I'd make it two different actions, but you can send a value to the action

```
{{action slide "up"}}

slide: function(type){
  console.log(type);
}
```

Comment: they kind of do the same thing

Comment: yeah, for sure, it's just a preference of mine.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone

`<Button @clicked={{fn (action "doAct" true)}} @label="Slide Up"/>`

`<Button @clicked={{fn (action "doAct" false)}} @label="Slide Down"/>`

`doAct(isSlideUp){ console.log(isSlideUp) }`

You can pass param in this way.